# How to fix out TF53001 issue in TFS2015?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

Working with TFS2015 Upade2 and VS2015 Update2. Everything works well until one of the project collection can't add, rename, delete files. Will prompt an error Message:

> TF53001: The database operation was canceled by an Administrator.

This issue can  be reproduced by everyone in my team even with team project collection administrator. How to fix out the issue? Any help would be appreciate!

Thanks Tomhans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to resolve this error, you might want to start by checking the version of your SQL instance hosting the TFS databases.

To find the version of the SQL instance run the query `‘select @@version’`. The version list for SQL can be found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2015/10/08/tf53001-the-database-operation-was-canceled-by-an-administrator/).

If your SQL version is **lesser than SQL 2014 CU4** then update it to CU4 or a higher update. And then try it again. More details please refer [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2015/10/08/tf53001-the-database-operation-was-canceled-by-an-administrator/) from MSDN.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm using SQL2014 update2. I think this is not the root cause.

Comment: The error resolved when I change the service back to the original  service account (which was NT Service/MSSQLSERVER) from Domain user and restarted the SQL Server service. You gave me a   a  correctly directiondirection. Thank you for your time any way.

Comment: Took me a while to convince the DBA to patch SQL with CU4, but when it was done - everything worked again. What is confusing is that this error does not seem to be caused by changes like updates, patches etc. At least that was the case in our instance.